# Determine how bash or sh was called

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, process, bourne-shell

From a bash or sh shell, how can I determine if it was called with the `bash` or `sh` command, a login shell, an xterm, and, in the case of the former, how was that called?

For example, if I call `bash` from an xterm, and then call it again, inside that instance, it might output something like

```
me@mylinuxmachine:~$ bash
me@mylinuxmachine:~$ bash
me@mylinuxmachine:~$ magic_command
Called by /bin/bash {
    Called by /bin/bash {
        Called by xterm
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `pstree` for this:

```
$ bash
bash-4.4$ pstree -p "$$"
-+= 00001 root /sbin/init
 \-+= 85460 kk tmux: server (/tmp/tmux-1000/default) (tmux)
   \-+= 96572 kk -ksh93 (ksh93)
     \-+= 72474 kk bash
       \-+= 14184 kk pstree -p 72474
         \-+- 51965 kk sh -c ps -kaxwwo user,pid,ppid,pgid,command
           \--- 91001 kk ps -kaxwwo user
```

The `pstree` utility will show the parent-child relationships for all processes currently running on the system.  With `-p "$$"` you restrict its output to only contain processes related the the current shell (whose process ID is stored in the `$` variable).

To cut the output off at the point where it gets to the current shell, you could use `sed`:

```
bash-4.4$ pstree -p "$$" | sed "/= $$ /q"
-+= 00001 root /sbin/init
 \-+= 85460 kk tmux: server (/tmp/tmux-1000/default) (tmux)
   \-+= 96572 kk -ksh93 (ksh93)
     \-+= 72474 kk bash
```

For Linux systems, which apparently use a different implementation of this utility from what I'm using (on OpenBSD), you may want to use

```
$ pstree -salup "$$"
```

to get a similar output, and

```
$ pstree -salup "$$" | sed "/,$$\$/q"
```

to cut the output off at the point where it gets to the current shell.

Here's a shell function `pls` (for "process `ls`", that's the best I could come up with) that does the above for any given PID (or the PID of the current shell if left out):

```
function pls
{
  local pid="${1:-$$}"
  pstree -salup "$pid" | sed "/,$pid\$/q"
}
```

Comment: What implementation of `pstree` is that? With the one from PSmisc, I need `pstree -salup "$$"` to have something similar.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas This is on OpenBSD with `pstree` from http://www.thp.uni-duisburg.de/pstree/

Comment: How would the latter example work with the `sed` command?

Comment: @AnEpicPerson Thanks, I missed that detail. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I have created an alias `alias whereami='pstree -salup "$$" | sed "/,$$\$/q"'`, which responds to the command `whereami`.